# Custom UITableViewCell + Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

While in editing mode, to the right of the `UITableViewCell` there is an icon of 3 lines with a hand holding function that can be dragged and dropped by `UITableViewCell` and I'm having trouble changing the image for that icon or changing the colors for that icon.

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, 3 dots to resize the UITableViewCell.
If you add any image view to your cell class, you can change the image by selecting the image view & in the attribute inspector (4th option) set the image name.
Your image should be added into your assets.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still don't understand what you mean, can you send me a piece of code for reference?